Given a directed graph with edge weights $0$ or $1$, is there a way to find an odd cycle in $\mathsf{NC}$?
Given a directed graph with edge weights $0$ or $1$, is there a way to find an odd weight cycle in $\mathsf{NC}$? I think the decision version is in $\mathsf{NC}$, but I am not sure about the search version.

$\mathsf{NC}$ is a class of decision problems. I assume you mean to ask whether the search version is in $\mathsf{FNC}$, where for any class $C$ of decision problems, $\mathsf FC$ is the class of functions $F\colon\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^*$ such that $|F(x)|\le|x|^{O(1)}$, and the bitgraph
$$\{(x,1^i):\text{$i$th bit of $F(x)$ is $1$}\}$$
is decidable in $C$.
The answer is positive; better yet, such a cycle—if it exists—can be found in $\mathsf{FNL}$.
First, a simpler problem:

Lemma: Given a directed graph $G$ and two vertices $s$ and $t$ such that $t$ is reachable from $s$, we can find a directed path from $s$ to $t$ by an $\mathsf{FNL}$ function.

Proof:
We will define a canonical path from $s$ to $t$ such that given $i$ in unary, we can find the $i$th bit of the description of the path in $\mathsf{NL}$.
Recall that the problem “given $l$ and vertices $s$ and $t$, is $t$ reachable from $s$ in $l$ steps?” is in $\mathsf{NL}$, and so is its complement by the Immerman—Szelepcsényi theorem. Thus, we can find the least length $l$ of a path from $s$ to $t$ by a nondeterministic logspace algorithm: we nondeterministically guess and verify the correct answer to the above-mentioned problem for $l=0,1,2,\dots$ until the answer is positive.
Then we define a path $x_0,\dots,x_l$ by $x_0=s$, and for each $j<l$, $x_{j+1}$ is the least vertex (in numerical order, identifying the set of vertices with $[n]$) such that there is an edge from $x_j$ to $x_{j+1}$, and $t$ is reachable from $x_{j+1}$ in $l-j-1$ steps. As above, given $x_j$, we can compute $x_{j+1}$ in nodeterministic logspace. Thus, we can compute vertices of the path one by one (we do not store the whole path, but only the current $x_j$). We keep track of the bit-length of the description of the path, and upon reaching the $i$th bit, we output it. QED
Now, for the problem in the question, we proceed similarly. Let $G=(V,E)$ be the input graph, and for $j=1,2$, let $G_j=(V,E_j)$ be the graph with an edge from $u$ to $v$ iff there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$ that uses exactly $j$ edges of weight $1$. The original problem is equivalent to: find vertices $u$ and $v$, a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$ that lifts a path in $G_2$, and a path from $v$ to $u$ in $G$ that lifts an edge in $G_1$.
Note that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are both $\mathsf{NL}$-computable. Using a similar strategy as above, we compute the least $u$ and $v$ in numerical order for which such paths exist, and the least length $l$ of a $G_2$-path from $u$ to $v$. Define a $G_2$-path $x_0,\dots,x_l$ from $u$ to $v$ such that $x_0=u$ and $x_{j+1}$ is the least vertex with a $G_2$-edge from $x_j$ from which $v$ is $G_2$-reachable in $l-j-1$ steps. For each $j<l$, we similarly define a canonical $G$-path from $x_j$ to $x_{j+1}$ that goes through two edges of weight $1$, and a $G$-path from $v$ to $u$ that goes through one edge of weight $1$. The resulting path is computable vertex by vertex in nondeterministic logspace, keeping track of the last constructed $x_j$, the last constructed vertex of the $G$-path from $x_j$ to $x_{j+1}$, and the bit-length of the description of the path so far.

Hi Emil, thanks for you answer! I am not familiar with Immerman—Szelepcsényi and I'm not sure why it is needed here. Why can't we simply check if there is a path for l=n, n-1,n-2.... and keep updating a counter whenever a path exists. The final value of counter will be the length of the shortest path.

Also, could you clarify what you mean by 'lifts a path' and 'lifts an edge'?

If you nondeterministically try to guess a path of length $n,n-1,n-2,\dots$, and the machine finds a path of length $7$, but no path of shorter length, you do not know whether (1) the shortest path is indeed of length $7$, or whether (2) there is a path of length $4$, but the machine guessed it wrong. In order to compute the minimal length, you need to have a way of nondeterministically certifying both existence and nonexistence of paths of given length.

Lifting means the obvious thing. By definition, there is an edge in $G_j$ from $u$ to $v$ iff there exists a path in $G$ from $u$ to $v$ that has exactly $j$ edges of weight $1$ (and arbitrary edges of weight $0$). Any such path is said to lift the $G_j$ edge $u\to v$. Then, a path $p$ in $G$ lifts a path $u_0\dots u_k$ in $G_j$ if $p$ is a concatenation of paths $p_0,\dots,p_{k-1}$ such that $p_i$ lifts the edge $u_i\to u_{i+1}$ for each $i<k$.
